# Hbase as a source in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

Is there a standard way to treat Hbase as a source to spark streaming?

Hbase -> Spark Streaming

If not, for simple use case will timerange filter to get the latest cell, and keep track of processed timestamp work?